# How do I change font in Modern Resume to Calibri font

Tags: fonts, pdftex, moderncv

I liked the `modern resume` style. I wanted to use it but I have to submit it in `Calibri` font. How do I change everything font in the document?

Resume: https://www.overleaf.com/project/60b6e7918740f511dfa13e9b
code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman    
\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
\usepackage{color}
   \usepackage[scale=0.79]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
\firstname{Shane} % Your first name
\familyname{Thirkell} % Your last name
% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Ocean Engineering}
\address{12 Chain Bridge Drive}{Newburyport, Massachusetts 01950}
\mobile{(978)-270-0371}
\email{$shane \textunderscore thirkell@my.uri.edu$}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle % Print the CV title
\section{Education}    
\cventry{2015-2018}{Bachelor of Science}{University of Rhode Island}{Narragansett, RI}{\textit{GPA - 3.42}}{\bfseries Ocean Engineering, Renewable Energy Track}  % Arguments not required can be left empty
%------------------------------------------------    
\subsection{Junior Spring Semester Project}    
\cventry{2018}{Flow Mapping (Particle Image Velocimetry)}{Research Experiment}{}{}{This was an experiment in fluid dynamics with respect to a cylinder subjected to a constant flow. The water is seeded with small particles that are illuminated by a powerful laser. A cylinder is moved mechanically in various patterns mimicking theoretical 'free vibration' due to vortex shedding. The images are processed and analyzed in MATLAB and the resulting turblence/vorticity can be visualized. The forces experienced by the body are widely applicable (energy generation, structural pile requirements). Results were used in graduate student Erdem Aktosun's research.}    
\end{document}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

I want to change the document font to `calibri`. Presently `default fonts` are `sans` or `roman`. So, how do I introduce `calibri` here? I tried following but no change in the font.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,calibri]{moderncv}
```

Update: After below answer, I am getting the error:
[image]

Comment: Welcome! Could you please paste in a MWE, rather than linking to an external site? The link might go dead, and questions here should be useful as references to future readers with the same problem.

Comment: @Davislor Yes! I did change my question and included an MWE. Thanks

Comment: Given that Calibri is a commercial font, do you actually have access to it on your computer/in overleaf?

Comment: @daleif first time hearing this! `Calibri` is a commercial font. Never knew it and full of surprise at the same time. I have no idea. If I cannot find it, I have to discard the latex resume, resort back to MS word resume.

Comment: @Mainland Read my answer carefully. You need to remove the spaces from the font names on Overleaf (and in the `\setsansfont` command) and you need to compile with LuaLaTeX not pdfLaTeX. On Overleaf this is done by clicking on the Menu icon at the top left and then choosing LuaLaTeX as the Compiler.

Comment: You can use the free substitute Carlito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Calibri font is not distributed with a standard TeX distribution, you will need to upload a copy of the fonts to your project folder in Overleaf. My version of Calibri seems to have 4 faces: `Calibri.ttf`, `Calibri Italic.ttf`, `Calibri Bold.ttf` and `Calibri Bold Italic.ttf`. You will need to upload all of these, and remove the spaces from the names (if that's how they appear on your system.)  Whether uploading the fonts to Overleaf violates the licensing agreement of the font is up to you to decide.

Then compile your document using LuaLaTeX and use `fontspec` to set the font. You must do this *after* loading the `moderncvstyle`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman    
\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[BoldFont={CalibriBold.ttf},ItalicFont=CalibriItalic.ttf,BoldItalicFont=CalibriBoldItalic.ttf]{Calibri.ttf}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
\usepackage{color}
   \usepackage[scale=0.79]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
\firstname{Shane} % Your first name
\familyname{Thirkell} % Your last name
% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Ocean Engineering}
\address{12 Chain Bridge Drive}{Newburyport, Massachusetts 01950}
\mobile{(978)-270-0371}
\email{shane\_thirkell@my.uri.edu}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle % Print the CV title
\section{Education}    
\cventry{2015-2018}{Bachelor of Science}{University of Rhode Island}{Narragansett, RI}{\textit{GPA - 3.42}}{\bfseries Ocean Engineering, Renewable Energy Track}  % Arguments not required can be left empty
%------------------------------------------------    
\subsection{Junior Spring Semester Project}    
\cventry{2018}{Flow Mapping (Particle Image Velocimetry)}{Research Experiment}{}{}{This was an experiment in fluid dynamics with respect to a cylinder subjected to a constant flow. The water is seeded with small particles that are illuminated by a powerful laser. A cylinder is moved mechanically in various patterns mimicking theoretical 'free vibration' due to vortex shedding. The images are processed and analyzed in MATLAB and the resulting turblence/vorticity can be visualized. The forces experienced by the body are widely applicable (energy generation, structural pile requirements). Results were used in graduate student Erdem Aktosun's research.}    
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: It worked. I actually used it on the desktop latex. I used `xeLatex` and had the fonts downloaded, installed in the same folder.

Comment: @Mainland If you are not using Overleaf, LuaLaTeX should find the fonts in their regular location.

Comment: I included the spacing and it worked. That was not an issue. Another question: how do I reduce the space between `Ocean Engineering` and `Education` in the above screenshot?

Comment: @Mainland That's a completely different question. You can ask it separately.

Comment: Thanks. Here it is: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599704/how-to-reduce-spacing-in-a-template-resume