# How to reduce spacing in a template resume

Tags: vertical-alignment, moderncv

I am using a template resume. I find the spacing after the title `Ocean Engineering` and first section `Education` is large, want to reduce it. I tried a simple approach, itdid not work.

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{black} 
\usepackage[body={8.5in, 11in},top=1in, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}    
\firstname{Shane} % Your first name
\familyname{Thirkell} % Your last name
% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Ocean Engineering}
\address{12 Chain Bridge Drive}{Newburyport, Massachusetts 01950}
\mobile{(978)-270-0371}
\email{shane \textunderscore thirkell@my.uri.edu}    
\begin{document}        
    \makecvtitle % Print the CV title    
    \section{Education}
    \cventry{2015-2018}{Bachelor of Science}{University of Rhode Island}{Narragansett, RI}{\textit{GPA - 3.42}}{\bfseries Ocean Engineering, Renewable Energy Track}  % Arguments not required can be left empty
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please remove the font stuff from this question. It's not relevant, and will just annoy people since Calibri is a commercial font that people won't necessarily have. And there's no need to show the Overleaf screenshot. Just show the screenshot of the output PDF.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes! removed the font code and unrelavant screenshot parts. Thanks

Comment: Well either way, the screen shot of the output, not the editing environment is what's relevant.

Comment: Most computer can make screen grabs of just relevant parts of the screen

Comment: why is your email in math? `$shane \textunderscore thirkell@my.uri.edu$`

Comment: `\vspace*{-1cm}` before the section?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Solved my problem. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\vspace*{-1cm}` before the section.

Answer (score 2):

With the current version of `moderncv`, version 2.1.0, you can patch the command creating the header of your cv including your not wanted space (`\\[2.5em]`) in your preamble like this:

```
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{% <==============================================
  \\[2.5em]%
  }{%
  \\[1em]% <========================================================= change 1em to anything you like
  }{%success
  }{%failure
  }
```

With the following complete MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{casual} % head 2 body 1 foot 1
\moderncvcolor{black} 
\usepackage[body={8.5in, 11in},top=1in, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}    

\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{% <==============================================
  \\[2.5em]%
  }{%
  \\[1em]% <========================================================= change 1em to anything you like
  }{%success
  }{%failure
  }

\firstname{Shane} % Your first name
\familyname{Thirkell} % Your last name
% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Ocean Engineering}
\address{12 Chain Bridge Drive}{Newburyport, Massachusetts 01950}
\mobile{(978)-270-0371}
\email{shane \textunderscore thirkell@my.uri.edu}
 
 
\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle % Print the CV title
    \section{Education}
    \cventry{2015-2018}{Bachelor of Science}{University of Rhode Island}{Narragansett, RI}{\textit{GPA - 3.42}}{\bfseries Ocean Engineering, Renewable Energy Track}  % Arguments not required can be left empty
\end{document}
```

you get the following wished pdf:

[image: wished pdf]